# I can't makemigration appname in Django project

Tags: django, django-models

After completed, I pushed and rebase git master, database in my project is locked. I removed database and create new, but I don't see table for Model in models.py. How should I fix? Help me

## models.py

```
class UserInfor(models.Model):
    GENDERS = (
        ('nam', "Nam"),
        ('nữ', "Nữ"),
        ('khác', "Khác")
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDERS, max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

## error

No changes detected

Comment: `database in my project is locked` how is that? `I can't makemigration` why?

Comment: `No changes detected` this means you already have all the needed migration files created.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `python manage.py migrate` to re-create your DB from scratch as you deleted it.

Comment: but what I wrote in models.py isn't migrated

Comment: Can you provide some code ? It's hard to guess what's wrong in your program with only two sentences of context.

Comment: In your title you say that you use `makemigrations appname` try it without `appname` ? It's a wild guess (and my last attempt) as I dont see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your app has been added to your project's `settings.py`

example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    ...................
    ...................
    'yourappname'
]
```

If you've done that already, check and see if you've also registered your `UserInfor` model in your 'admin.py`

```
from .models import UserInfor

admin.site.register(UserInfor)
```

If all the above checks out, you should be able to run your `migrations` and see your model's table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete db and files from migrations folder except **init**.py

then `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`